# FileOutputStream vs FileWriter

Tags: java

Коллеги, прошу помочь. Есть 2 схожих кода, копирующих файл:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileInputName);
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileOutputName);
int nextSmbl = fileReader.read();
while (nextSmbl > 0) {
    fileWriter.write(nextSmbl);
    nextSmbl = fileReader.read();
```

и

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileInputName);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileOutputName);
int nextSmbl = fileInputStream.read();
while (nextSmbl > 0) {
    fileOutputStream.write(nextSmbl);
    nextSmbl = fileInputStream.read();
```

В первом случае если `fileWriter` не `flush()` или `close()` - файл создается, но в него ничего не копируется.
Во втором случае - все копируется без `flush()` или `close()`.
Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileWriter - буферизованный, а FileOutputStream - нет

Comment: Это не относится через System.out к InputStream, у которого есть DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 8192?

Comment: @Alexey не очень понял вопроса, System.out используется для вывода в консоль, а InputStream - это поток ввода. Также InputStream, как OutputStream - не буферизованные потоки, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE совсем про другое. Если вы имеете в виду почему System.out выводит сразу и не теряет данные, это потому что там используется PrintStream с autoFlush свойством, после каждого вывода в out вызывается flush

Comment: Супер, всё понял, autoFlush - спасибо!